# Tokenize() in nltk.TweetTokenizer returning integers by splitting

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

Tokenize() in `nltk.TweetTokenizer` returning the 32-bit integers by dividing them into digits. It is only happening to some certain numbers, and I don't see any reason why?

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer 
>>> tw = TweetTokenizer()
>>> tw.tokenize('the 23135851162 of 3151942776...')
[u'the', u'2313585116', u'2', u'of', u'3151942776', u'...']
```

The input `23135851162` has been split into `[u'2313585116', u'2']`

Interestingly, it seems to segment all numbers into 10 digits

```
>>> tw.tokenize('the 231358511621231245 of 3151942776...')
[u'the', u'2313585116', u'2123124', u'5', u'of', u'3151942776', u'...']
>>> tw.tokenize('the 231123123358511621231245 of 3151942776...')
[u'the', u'2311231233', u'5851162123', u'1245', u'of', u'3151942776', u'...']
```

---

The length of number token affects the tokenization:

```
>>> s = 'the 1234567890 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'12345678', u'90', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 123456789 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'12345678', u'9', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 12345678 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'12345678', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 1234567 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'1234567', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 123456 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'123456', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 12345 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'12345', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 1234 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'1234', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 123 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'123', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 12 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'12', u'of']
>>> s = 'the 1 of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'1', u'of']
```

If contiguous digits + whitespace goes beyond length 10:

```
>>> s = 'the 123 456 78901234  of'
>>> tw.tokenize(s)
[u'the', u'123 456 7890', u'1234', u'of']
```

Comment: Interesting! Good question too! Could you post the code and the full input and output so that it's easier for us to help you?

Comment: Is it happening with all the integers?

Comment: Nope, it only splits when the length of number token is > 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

It seems to be a bug/feature of the `TweetTokenizer()` which we're unsure what motivates this.

Read on to find out where the bug/feature occurs...

---

## In Long

Looking at the `tokenize()` function in TweetTokenizer, before the actual tokenizing, the tokenizer does some preprocessing:

- First, it remove entities from text by converting them to their corresponding unicode character through the `_replace_html_entities()` function
- Optionally, it removes username handles using the `remove_handles()` function.
- Optionally, it normalize the word length through the reduce_lengthening function
- Then, shortens the *problematic sequences of characters* using the `HANG_RE` regex
- Lastly, the actual tokenization takes place through the `WORD_RE` regex

After the `WORD_RE` regex, it

- optionally preserve the case of emoticons before lowercasing the tokenized output

**In code:**

```
def tokenize(self, text):
    """
    :param text: str
    :rtype: list(str)
    :return: a tokenized list of strings; concatenating this list returns\
    the original string if `preserve_case=False`
    """
    # Fix HTML character entities:
    text = _replace_html_entities(text)
    # Remove username handles
    if self.strip_handles:
        text = remove_handles(text)
    # Normalize word lengthening
    if self.reduce_len:
        text = reduce_lengthening(text)
    # Shorten problematic sequences of characters
    safe_text = HANG_RE.sub(r'\1\1\1', text)
    # Tokenize:
    words = WORD_RE.findall(safe_text)
    # Possibly alter the case, but avoid changing emoticons like :D into :d:
    if not self.preserve_case:
        words = list(map((lambda x : x if EMOTICON_RE.search(x) else
                          x.lower()), words))
    return words
```

By default, the handle stripping and length reduction doesn't kick in, unless specified by user.

```
class TweetTokenizer:
    r"""
    Tokenizer for tweets.

        >>> from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
        >>> tknzr = TweetTokenizer()
        >>> s0 = "This is a cooool #dummysmiley: :-) :-P <3 and some arrows < > -> <--"
        >>> tknzr.tokenize(s0)
        ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cooool', '#dummysmiley', ':', ':-)', ':-P', '<3', 'and', 'some', 'arrows', '<', '>', '->', '<--']

    Examples using `strip_handles` and `reduce_len parameters`:

        >>> tknzr = TweetTokenizer(strip_handles=True, reduce_len=True)
        >>> s1 = '@remy: This is waaaaayyyy too much for you!!!!!!'
        >>> tknzr.tokenize(s1)
        [':', 'This', 'is', 'waaayyy', 'too', 'much', 'for', 'you', '!', '!', '!']
    """

    def __init__(self, preserve_case=True, reduce_len=False, strip_handles=False):
        self.preserve_case = preserve_case
        self.reduce_len = reduce_len
        self.strip_handles = strip_handles
```

Let's go through the steps and regexes:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import _replace_html_entities
>>> s = 'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> _replace_html_entities(s)
u'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
```

**Checked, `_replace_html_entities()` isn't the culprit.**

By default, `remove_handles()` and `reduce_lengthening()` is skipped but for sanity sake, let's see:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import _replace_html_entities
>>> s = 'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> _replace_html_entities(s)
u'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import remove_handles, reduce_lengthening
>>> remove_handles(_replace_html_entities(s))
u'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> reduce_lengthening(remove_handles(_replace_html_entities(s)))
u'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
```

**Checked too, neither of the optional functions are behaving badly**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> HANG_RE = re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])\1{3,}')
>>> HANG_RE.sub(r'\1\1\1', s)
'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
```

**Klar! The `HANG_RE` is cleared of its name too**

```
>>> import re
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import REGEXPS
>>> WORD_RE = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> WORD_RE.findall(s)
['the', '2313585234', '2342342116', '2', 'of', '3151942776', '...']
```

**Achso! That's where the splits appear!**

Now let's look deeper into the `WORD_RE`, it's a tuple of regexes.

The first is a massive URL pattern regex from  https://gist.github.com/winzig/8894715

Let's go through them one by one:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import REGEXPS
>>> patt = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> s = 'the 231358523423423421162 of 3151942776...'
>>> patt.findall(s)
['the', '2313585234', '2342342116', '2', 'of', '3151942776', '...']
>>> patt = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS[:1]), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> patt.findall(s)
[]
>>> patt = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS[:2]), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> patt.findall(s)
['2313585234', '2342342116', '3151942776']
>>> patt = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS[1:2]), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> patt.findall(s)
['2313585234', '2342342116', '3151942776']
```

**Ah ha! It seems like the 2nd regex from `REGEXPS` is causing the problem!!**

If we look at https://github.com/alvations/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/casual.py#L122:

```
# The components of the tokenizer:
REGEXPS = (
    URLS,
    # Phone numbers:
    r"""
    (?:
      (?:            # (international)
        \+?[01]
        [\-\s.]*
      )?
      (?:            # (area code)
        [\(]?
        \d{3}
        [\-\s.\)]*
      )?
      \d{3}          # exchange
      [\-\s.]*
      \d{4}          # base
    )"""
    ,
    # ASCII Emoticons
    EMOTICONS
    ,
    # HTML tags:
    r"""<[^>\s]+>"""
    ,
    # ASCII Arrows
    r"""[\-]+>|<[\-]+"""
    ,
    # Twitter username:
    r"""(?:@[\w_]+)"""
    ,
    # Twitter hashtags:
    r"""(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)"""
    ,
    # email addresses
    r"""[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.(?:[\w-]\.?)+[\w-]"""
    ,
    # Remaining word types:
    r"""
    (?:[^\W\d_](?:[^\W\d_]|['\-_])+[^\W\d_]) # Words with apostrophes or dashes.
    |
    (?:[+\-]?\d+[,/.:-]\d+[+\-]?)  # Numbers, including fractions, decimals.
    |
    (?:[\w_]+)                     # Words without apostrophes or dashes.
    |
    (?:\.(?:\s*\.){1,})            # Ellipsis dots.
    |
    (?:\S)                         # Everything else that isn't whitespace.
    """
    )
```

The second regex from REGEXP tries to parse numbers as phone-numbers:

```
# Phone numbers:
    r"""
    (?:
      (?:            # (international)
        \+?[01]
        [\-\s.]*
      )?
      (?:            # (area code)
        [\(]?
        \d{3}
        [\-\s.\)]*
      )?
      \d{3}          # exchange
      [\-\s.]*
      \d{4}          # base
    )"""
```

The pattern tries to recognize

- Optionally, the first digits will be matched as international code.
- the next 3 digits as the area code
- optionally followed by a dash
- then 3 more digits which is the (telecom) exchange code
- another optional dash
- lastly 4 digit base phone number.

See https://regex101.com/r/BQpnsg/1 for a detailed explanation.

**That's why it's trying to split contiguous digits up into 10 digits block!!**

But note the quirks, since the phone number regex is hard coded, it is possible to catch real phone numbers in the `\d{3}-d{3}-\d{4}` or `\d{10}` patterns, but if the dashes are in other order, it won't work:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import REGEXPS
>>> patt = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(REGEXPS[1:2]), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
>>> s = '231-358-523423423421162'
>>> patt.findall(s)
['231-358-5234', '2342342116']
>>> s = '2313-58-523423423421162'
>>> patt.findall(s)
['5234234234']
```

**Can we fix it?**

See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1799

Comment: The phone # recognition RE is the culprit.

Comment: Yes yes, still typing... Don't spoil the FUN!

Answer (score 1):

There is a part of the `TweetTokenizer` regular expression that recognizes phone numbers in every imaginable format (search for *# Phone numbers:* in this document: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/casual.html#TweetTokenizer). Some 10-digit numbers happen to look like 10-digit phone numbers. That's why they are converted into separate tokens.